# issue accessing JSON object using key name with . but works with []

Tags: javascript, arrays, json, object, key

What is the reason here while accessing JSON object using . gives error but using [] it works? what is the correct syntax to access the JSON object key?

This syntax gives the error:

> var obj2G = obj.2G;

This syntax is working but why need to access this way?

> var obj2G = obj["2G"];

```js
var obj = {
  "2G": [{
    "essid": "SINGTEL-662F",
    "authmode": "psk psk2",
    "authkey": "0000026159",
    "isEnable": "1",
    "isHidden": "0",
    "hwaddr": "E0:8E:3C:00:66:30",
    "opmode": "ap"
  }, {
    "essid": "GUEST1-662F",
    "authmode": "psk psk2",
    "authkey": "aabbccddee",
    "isEnable": "0",
    "isHidden": "0",
    "hwaddr": "",
    "opmode": "ap"
  }, {
    "essid": "GUEST2-662F",
    "authmode": "psk psk2",
    "authkey": "aabbccddee",
    "isEnable": "0",
    "isHidden": "0",
    "hwaddr": "",
    "opmode": "ap"
  }, {
    "essid": "GUEST3-662F",
    "authmode": "psk psk2",
    "authkey": "aabbccddee",
    "isEnable": "0",
    "isHidden": "0",
    "hwaddr": "62:8E:3C:00:66:33",
    "opmode": "ap"
  }],
  "5G": [{
    "essid": "SINGTEL-662F(5G)",
    "authmode": "psk psk2",
    "authkey": "0000026159",
    "isEnable": "1",
    "isHidden": "0",
    "hwaddr": "E0:8E:3C:00:66:31",
    "opmode": "ap"
  }, {
    "essid": "GUEST1(5G)-662F",
    "authmode": "psk psk2",
    "authkey": "aabbccddee",
    "isEnable": "0",
    "isHidden": "0",
    "hwaddr": "6a:8e:3c:00:66:32",
    "opmode": "ap"
  }, {
    "essid": "GUEST2(5G)-662F",
    "authmode": "psk psk2",
    "authkey": "aabbccddee",
    "isEnable": "0",
    "isHidden": "0",
    "hwaddr": "",
    "opmode": "ap"
  }, {
    "essid": "GUEST3(5G)-662F",
    "authmode": "psk psk2",
    "authkey": "aabbccddee",
    "isEnable": "0",
    "isHidden": "0",
    "hwaddr": "6a:8e:3c:00:66:30",
    "opmode": "ap"
  }]
}

obj2G = obj["2G"];
console.log(obj2G);

obj2G = obj.2G;
console.log(obj2G);
```

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1661197/what-characters-are-valid-for-javascript-variable-names

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you use dot notation:

> property must be a valid JavaScript identifier, i.e. a sequence of alphanumerical characters, also including the underscore ("_") and dollar sign ("$"), that cannot start with a number. For example, object.$1 is valid, while object.1 is not.

In that case, you have to use bracket notation:

> property_name is a string. The string does not have to be a valid identifier; it can have any value, e.g. "1foo", "!bar!", or even " " (a space).

See the documentation: https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Property_accessors

It's worth mentioning that you have to use bracket notation if you want to access a property using a variable. For instance:

```
var myName = "foo";
var myObject = { foo: 42};
console.log(myObject.myName);//returns undefined
```

But:

```
var myName = "foo";
var myObject = { foo: 42};
console.log(myObject[myName]);//returns 42
```

Answer (score 2):

Object properties must start with a letter when used in dot notation. It's just a rule in Javascript. You can name property literally `'*&^'` but you have to do it via `[]` notation.

`2G` starts with a number thus requires `[]` notation.

Comment: i understood overall but can't understood what you wrote about `'*&^'` ?

Comment: I mean you can add a property named `*&^` to an object like `object['*&^'] = 6;`

Comment: Found an article [related to this](https://mathiasbynens.be/notes/javascript-identifiers-es6)

Answer (score 1):

From the documentation to [Property Accessor](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Property_Accessors#Dot_notation) for dot notation:

> In this code, property must be a valid JavaScript identifier, i.e. a sequence of alphanumerical characters, also including the underscore ("_") and dollar sign ("$"), that cannot start with a number. For example, object.$1 is valid, while object.1 is not.

And to [Variable](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Grammar_and_types#Variables)

> A JavaScript identifier must start with a letter, underscore (_), or dollar sign ($); subsequent characters can also be digits (0-9). Because JavaScript is case sensitive, letters include the characters "A" through "Z" (uppercase) and the characters "a" through "z" (lowercase).

The result is, a variable or a property in dot notation with starting number can not be used.